# Div tag margin not working

Tags: html, css, facebook

Designing the facebook login page for practise using only html and css.But Here I'm facing some problem.Don't know what it is.Here I want to decrease the top margin of class "loginArea" but cant do it.So the facebook logo is okey but the login area is totally different from the genuine facebook page.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

.logoArea {
  height: 35px;
  width: 100px;
  background: url(media/6cVHHozUQSt.png) no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 40px 40px 0 200px;
}

.mainArea {
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: auto;
}

header.mainHeader:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

header.mainHeader {
  background: #3a5797;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.mainHeader .logoArea {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.mainHeader .loginArea {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}

.loginArea .userName,
.loginArea .password {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

.loginArea input[type="text"],
.loginArea input[type="password"] {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 2px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #29487d;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.loginArea .submitButton {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.loginArea label {
  font-size: 12px;
}

label[for="keepLogin"],
.loginArea a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #9CABC6;
}

#keepLogin {
  margin: 0;
}

.submitButton input {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #29487d;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Facebook- Log In or Sign Up</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>
  <header class="mainHeader">
    <div class="mainArea">
      <div class="logoArea">
        <img id="logo" src="media/6cVHHozUQSt.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="loginArea">
        <form action="#">
          <div class="userName">
            <label for="user">Email or Phone </label> <br/>
            <input type="text" id="user" /><br/>
            <input type="checkbox" id="keepLogin" />
            <label for="keepLogin"> Keep me Logged In</label>
          </div>
          <div class="password">
            <label for="password">Password </label><br/>
            <input type="password" id="password" /><br/>
            <a href="#">Forgotten you password?</a>
          </div>
          <div class="submitButton">
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In .loginArea class reduce top margin to 0 like this. Hope this helps you.

```
margin: 0 40px 0 200px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `width` or `margin` from `.mainHeader .logoArea` (or reduce it), so it does not block too much room.

Always be aware that the space an element actually uses is `height/width` + `padding` + `margin` + `border`, so in your case, the actual width the element takes is 50% plus 240px for the margins.

Comment: my problem was the hight above the login area.Not the width. I want to reduce the height above the login area

Comment: If you use your developer tools, you will see, that the logo box simply consumes too much width, so it forces the login element into the second row. Try removing the width from the logo box, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the margin for .logoArea so you could set box-sizing to border-box and instead of margin use padding.

The default value for box-sizing is content-box:

> This is the initial and default value as specified by the CSS standard. The width and height properties are measured including only the content, but not the padding, border or margin. Note: Padding, border & margin will be outside of the box e.g. IF .box {width: 350px;} THEN you apply {border: 10px solid black;} RESULT {rendered in the browser} a box of width: 370px.
>   So simply the dimension of element is calculated as, width = width of the content, and height = height of the content (excluding the values of border and padding).

so two ways of solving your issue:
 1. remove the margin
 2. set box-sizing to border-box + exchange margin with padding

pls check the box model and box-sizing for further infos :)

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

first of all at top place,

```
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

then change the margin in .logoArea to padding.

```
.logoArea {
 height: 35px;
 width: 100px;
 background: url(media/6cVHHozUQSt.png) no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 10px 40px 0 45px;
}
```